# Correct graph format for tipping system (C# Forms)

Tags: c#, forms, charts, format

I am working on a form where a user inputs lowest and highest tip rates, as well as lowest and highest dinner prices then presses a button that displays the tip amount for each price and each tip rate in a chart. The result is supposed to display info in this format:

```
Price   0.10   0.15   0.20
-------------------------
$10.00  $1.00  $1.50  $2.00
$20.00  $2.00  $3.00  $4.00
```

But I can't get it to work. I have tried displaying the info into labels by themselves or in flow layout and table layout panels but I can't get the results to display in the correct format. Everything else in my code is working the way it is supposed to. What do I need to do in order to correct this one thing? Any and all help is appreciated.

This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BriereAustinTippingTable2GUI
{
    public partial class TippingTable : Form
    {
        public TippingTable()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        double minTip;
        double maxTip;
        double minDinner;
        double maxDinner;

        double tip;
        double tipRate;

        const double TIPSTEP = 0.05;
        const double DINNERSTEP = 10.00;


        private void lblCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            minTip = Convert.ToDouble(txtMinRate.Text);
            maxTip = Convert.ToDouble(txtMaxRate.Text);
            minDinner = Convert.ToDouble(txtMinPrice.Text);
            maxDinner = Convert.ToDouble(txtMaxPrice.Text);

            lblTest1.Text += "Price  ";

            for (tipRate = minTip; tipRate <= maxTip; tipRate += TIPSTEP)
            {
                lblTest1.Text += ("   " + tipRate.ToString("F"));
            }

            lblTest1.Text += "\n________________________________________";

            tipRate = minTip;

            while (minDinner <= maxDinner)

            {
                lblTest2.Text += ("   \n" + minDinner.ToString("C"));

                while (tipRate <= maxTip)
                {
                    tip = minDinner * tipRate;

                    lblTest3.Text += (tip.ToString("F") + "");
                    //lblRow3.Text += "\n";
                    tipRate += 0.05;
                }

                minDinner += DINNERSTEP;

                tipRate = minTip;


            }




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I can't get the results to display in the correct format_ This is not a very helpful description of the problem you see. - The simplest way to create a tabular layout is to use a DtatGridView. Also: Charts seem to have nothing to do with your question at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are used using a label to try to display multiple lines. Use a text box instead and set it's multiline property to true so it can display multiple lines.

```
textbox1.Multiline = true;
```

It might be a good idea to set the readonly property to true as well so that the user cannot edit it.

Comment: Also he will need to use a fixed-size font such as Consolas for this.